# filtering a pandas DataFrame by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a **pandas** dataframe, and I want to filter it on some function of a number  of columns - the documentation seems to only talk about single columns. I did the following, but I kind of doubt that this would be the most efficient (or the most elegant) -- the code throws out those lines from the dataframe **dog** where the difference between the time stamps in two of the columns is greater than a threshold value:

```
flog = zip(dog['date1'], dog['date2'])

cog = [(x[0]-x[1]).days for x in flog]

dog['diff'] = cog

ddog = dog[(dog['diff']<5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your customized filter function this way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2), columns=['A', 'B'], index=np.random.choice(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 100))

Out[257]: 
         A       B
Y  -0.6444  0.9515
Y   0.0541  0.1810
X   1.0280 -2.1507
Y   0.5513 -0.6256
X  -1.4126  0.8487
Y  -0.4272 -0.7669
Z  -0.3358  0.8212
Z  -0.0328 -1.1885
Y   0.9210  1.7363
Z   1.2619 -2.5311
..     ...     ...
Y   0.4495 -0.1995
Y  -0.5025  0.8696
Z  -0.3178  0.5244
X   1.5752 -0.1915
Z   0.2572  0.1216
X  -0.5613  1.7869
Y  -0.4322  1.4184
Z   0.2402  0.9258
Z  -0.3328  1.7380
X  -1.9155  0.0929

[100 rows x 2 columns]

def my_filter(group):
    # say A^2 + B^2 > 1 
    selector = (group.A ** 2 + group.B ** 2) > 1
    return group[selector]

df.groupby(level=0).apply(my_filter)

Out[256]: 
          A       B
X X  1.0280 -2.1507
  X -1.4126  0.8487
  X -0.6299  0.8297
  X  0.8790 -0.5672
  X -2.1781  1.8232
  X  0.4533 -1.1098
  X  0.8996 -0.6523
  X -2.6023  0.2152
  X  1.5641 -1.0823
  X -0.4553  1.0037
..      ...     ...
Z Z -0.7860  1.3643
  Z  0.7350 -1.3309
  Z  0.9675 -0.9975
  Z -1.0461 -0.8538
  Z -0.9659  1.7430
  Z -0.9788  0.3100
  Z  1.6457  1.7855
  Z -2.0771  0.4892
  Z  0.0399 -1.6994
  Z -0.3328  1.7380

[61 rows x 2 columns]
```

We've removed 39 rows (from 100 to 61).

Answer (score 2):

Select your columns from the DataFrame and then apply your function (possibly a `lambda` expression depending on usage).

```
mask = dog[['date1', 'date2']].apply(lambda x: abs(x[0] - x[1]).days < 5, axis=1)
>>> dog[mask]
```

To illustrate:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': pd.date_range(start='2015-1-1', periods=10),
                   'date2': pd.date_range(start='2015-1-1', periods=10)[::-1]})
mask = df[['date1', 'date2']].apply(lambda x: abs(x[0] - x[1]).days < 5, axis=1)

>>> df
       date1      date2
0 2015-01-01 2015-01-10
1 2015-01-02 2015-01-09
2 2015-01-03 2015-01-08
3 2015-01-04 2015-01-07
4 2015-01-05 2015-01-06
5 2015-01-06 2015-01-05
6 2015-01-07 2015-01-04
7 2015-01-08 2015-01-03
8 2015-01-09 2015-01-02
9 2015-01-10 2015-01-01

>>> df[mask]
       date1      date2
3 2015-01-04 2015-01-07
4 2015-01-05 2015-01-06
5 2015-01-06 2015-01-05
6 2015-01-07 2015-01-04
```

Given the new date filtered DataFrame, you can then continue your analysis.

Comment: I am sure I am being dense, but if the DataFrame has several columns, then df[mask] will return the (full) DataFrame filtered by the mask?!

Comment: @IgorRivin Notice the `abs` function on the days.  I first differenced them, but noticed that more were passing my filter than expected due to negative days (e.g. -10 < 5 => TRUE).